# How to crop HTMLVideoElement in WebGL's texImage2D?

Tags: javascript, webgl, crop

I'm playing around with WebGL, and I can successfully render a video element to a WebGL context with [`texImage2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D). However, I'm now trying to crop this video element before rendering it. For example, I want to take the top half of the video element and draw it in the left half of my GL context; and the bottom half in the right half.

[image: image1]

**What is the best practice for this "crop action" in WebGL 1?**

I have figured out that I can adjust the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/viewport) to render something in the left/right half, but I can't seem to find how to crop.

It would be nice if [`texImage2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) supported offset and dimension parameters for video elements, but that's not the case.

Maybe I can adjust this in the texture parameters or something?

Answer (score 1):

In WebGL1 there is no easy way to crop at the `texImage2D` level. I suggest you just put the entire video frame into 1 texture and then use texture coordinates when rendering to select the part of the texture you want to display in each area

Comment: Same principe i use for 3d slot example : https://maximumroulette.com/welcome/3d_slot/  , Use blender or any 3d app   for modelling and setup textoreCord (UV EDITOR) . In uv editor you can (crop) split horizontal on two parts.